# access integer anywhere outside method in same class

Tags: java, android, integer, static-variables

i declared a `int jj` in side `onConfigurationChanged` function now i want to acces it outside `onConfigurationChanged`anywhare in same class.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final int jj=4;
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        final int jj=2;   
    }
}
```

i want to i access this variable in same class like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static int aa=jj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as a class field.  I don't know what you are doing with `aa`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int jj;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        jj=4;

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        jj=2;

    }
}
```

}

It's clear from the question that you do not really understand the basics of programming, OOP and Java.

I recommend that you complete some basic tutorials before continuing until you understand primitives vs objects, `final` and `static`.

You should also understand you that cannot treat an `Activity` like a POJO.

Comment: what i want is i want to pass int from `onConfigurationChanged` to static variable. note: aa is static int.

Comment: If you are not going to listen to the advice and answers that you are given, then I cannot help you.  I have already explained in your previous question that you should not use a `static` since you should not even try to access an `Activity` from another class.  If you are not interested in learning, then I am not interested in helping.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a class to hold global variables:

```
public class GlobalVariables {
     public static int jj = 0;
}
```

Then you can access it from everywhere by simply calling `GlobalVariables.jj`

e.g.

```
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GlobalVariables.jj=4;
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GlobalVariables.jj=2;
    }
```

and

```
    public static int aa= 0;
    ...
    aa = GlobalVariables.jj;
```

However, I strongly agree with Simon. You need to study the basics of Object Oriented Design because what you ask breaks a couple of the OOD principles and my suggested solution is definitely an overkill.